# Example of locally free sheaf or free sheaf.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a ringed space. 
Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules  on $X$.

> $\mathcal{S}$ is *free* if it is isomophic to a direct sum of copies
>   of $\mathcal{O}_X$.
>
> $\mathcal{S}$ is   *locally free*  if $X$ can be covered by open sets
>   $U$ for which $\mathcal{S}|_U$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_X|_U$ module.

Is there important example?

Or toy example?

Or loccaly free but not free case ?

[image]

Comment: This is probably silly, but a pathology can be easily seen when X is not connected.

Comment: If $X$ is a scheme, a locally free sheaf correspond to a vector bundle on $X$. Important examples are given by the tangent bundles and cotangent bundles. For a good example that is not locally free, you can look at skyscraper sheaf or more generally the sheaf $i_* \mathcal O_Z$ where $i : Z \to X$ is a closed immersion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $X$ a topological manifold and $\mathcal O_X$ its sheaf of continuous real-valued functions. Take a finite degree covering map $p : Y \to X$ and let $\mathcal S(U)$ consist of the continuous real-valued functions on $p^{-1}(U)$. (I.e. $\mathcal S = p_* \mathcal O_Y$.)

Then $\mathcal S$ is locally free, and it is free iff the covering map is trivial, i.e. when $Y$ is the product of $X$ with a discrete space.

---

Proof of free $\implies$ trivial cover: There are many ways to write this down; here's one which I think is most helpful:

Let $n = \dim_{\mathcal O_X(X)} \mathcal O_Y(Y)$. Take a basis $(f_i)$ of $\mathcal O_Y(Y)$ consisting of orthogonal idempotents, and let $Y_{f_i} = \{y \in Y : f_i(y) \neq 0 \} = \{ y \in Y : f_i(y) = 1 \}$. Because the $\mathcal O_Y(Y)$-ideal generated by the $f_i$ is $(1)$,
$$\bigcup_i Y_{f_i} = Y_1 = Y$$
When $i \neq j$, because $f_i f_j = 0$,
$$Y_{f_i} \cap Y_{f_j} = Y_0 = \varnothing$$
So that the $Y_{f_i}$ form a disjoint cover of $Y$. For each $i$ we have the restriction morphism $\mathcal O_Y(Y) \to \mathcal O_Y(Y_{f_i})$ which induces an isomorphism $\mathcal O_Y(Y)_{f_i} \cong O_Y(Y_{f_i})$.

Call $p_i$ the restriction of $p$ to $Y_{f_i}$. We show that each $p_i$ is a topological isomorphism. By assumption, we have an isomorphism
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal O_X(X)^n &\to \mathcal O_{Y}(Y) \\
(g_i) &\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n g_i \circ p \cdot f_i
\end{align*}$$
By localizing, for each $i$ this induces an isomorphism
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal O_X(X) & \to O_{Y}(Y)_{f_i} \to \mathcal O_{Y}(Y_{f_i}) \\
g &\mapsto g \circ p \cdot f_i \mapsto g \circ p_i \cdot f_i|_{Y_{f_i}} = g \circ p_i
\end{align*}$$

- We show that each $p_i$ is injective by using that the above map is surjective: take $y_1 \neq y_2 \in Y_{f_i}$, and take $f \in \mathcal O_Y(Y_{f_i})$ with $f(y_1) \neq f(y_2)$. By the above isomorphism, $f$ is of the form $g \circ p_i$. Because $f(y_1) \neq f(y_2)$, we must have $p_i(y_1) \neq p_i(y_2)$. Thus $p_i$ is injective.
- We show that each $p_i$ is surjective by using that the above map is injective: Assume $X$ and $Y$ are compact, then the argument is nicer: The set $Y_{f_i}$ is closed, hence compact. Suppose the closed set $p_i(Y_{f_i})$ does not equal $X$. Let $0 \neq g \in \mathcal O_X(X)$ be such that $X_g \subset X - p_i(Y_{f_i})$. Then $g \circ p_i = 0$, contradicting the injectivity. Thus $p_i$ is surjective.
  In the general case, injectivity of $g \mapsto g \circ p_i$ shows that each $p_i(Y_{f_i})$ is dense in $X$. Let $x \in X$. By assumption, there exists $m \in \mathbb N$ and $U \subset X$ open, containing $x$, such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of $m$ open sets $V_j$, such that the restriction of $p$ to each is a homeomorphism. Take $U$ connected. Then the $V_j$ are connected. Because the connected components of $Y$ are the $Y_{f_k}$, for every $j$ there exists $k(j)$ with $V_j \subset Y_{f_{k(j)}}$. Now because $p_i(Y_{f_i})$ is dense in $X$, it intersects $U$, so $Y_{f_i}$ must intersect one one the $V_j$. Then $i = k(j)$, so
  $$x \in U = p_i(V_j) \subset p_i(Y_{f_i})$$
  so that $p_i$ is surjective. (As a corollary, $m = n$ does not depend on $U$, so that $\deg p = \dim_{\mathcal O_{X}} \mathcal O_Y$.)
- Finally, that $p_i$ is a homeomorphism follows from the fact that it is a degree 1 covering map. Or alternatively, because $\mathcal O_X(X) \cong \mathcal O_{Y}(Y_{f_i})$, and the topologies on $X$ and $Y_{f_i}$ are induced by the open sets $X_g$ resp. $(Y_{f_i})_f$ for $g \in \mathcal O_X(X)$ resp. $f \in \mathcal O_Y(Y_{f_i})$. (Use bump functions.)

Comment: Why free implies trivial covering. I cannot prove it.

Comment: Tbh, I didn't verify that but it should be true. Try this: Take a $O_X(X)$-basis $(e_i)$ of $\mathcal O_Y(Y)$ and let $U_i\subset Y$ be the open set where $e_i=1$. Then show that the $U_i$ are isomorphic to $X$ via $p$. (I will think about this later)

Comment: I guess the isomorphism is $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \to  \mathcal{O}_Y(Y)^n$ instead $\mathcal{O}_X(X)^n \to  \mathcal{O}_Y(Y)$. The sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the induced sheaf from $\mathcal{O}_Y$. Or ... I am wrong ...??

Comment: I do think it is what I wrote. I defined $\mathcal S = p_* \mathcal O_Y$. It is $S(X)$ which is a free $\mathcal O_X(X)$-module, i.e. $\mathcal O_Y(Y)$ is a free $\mathcal O_X(X)$ module.

Comment: The covering map $p: Y \to X$ induces a morphism between ringed spaces  $(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y )  \to (X, \mathcal{O}_X := p_* \mathcal{O}_Y )$. Let $U$ be a suffinciently small open set of $X$ such that the inverse image is an union of $n$-copies of $U$. Then, $\mathcal{O}_X(U) = p_*\mathcal{O}_Y(U) =\mathcal{O}_Y(p^{-1}(U))=\mathcal{O}_Y(\cup_a^n U_a) = \sum ^n \mathcal{O}_Y(U_a)$. Thus I think 
 $\mathcal{O}_X \cong  \sum ^n \mathcal{O}_Y$.

Comment: If you **define** $\mathcal O_X = p_*\mathcal O_Y$, then yes, trivially $\mathcal O_X(X)$ is a free $\mathcal O_Y(Y)$-module, of rank 1. But that's not what's in my answer.